# InDesign combines all csv separated columns as one field in data merge

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I am trying to import an Excel CSV into InDesign Data Merge. Everytime I try to export the csv, it appears in Data Merge as only one field, with fields separated by semicolons, although in Excel I have multiple, comma separated fields.

I've done this plenty of times and have never experienced this problem. I have checked the language and regional settings on my laptop and these are set as comma separated. I've tried to use a txt file version, but Indesign won't accept it. I am now very much stuck! any suggestions?

Comment: After changing in Region setting did you restarted Windows? After that check if the "comma" use is saved.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that Excel uses semi-colon separators when InDesign looks for comas.
Prefer tabbed text format on export and everything will be fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Drop your CSV into a text editor and replace all `;` with `,`. Here's a sample of a CSV i recently used to build a photo grid in InDesign. So make sure you have commas everywhere separating the values, otherwise it doesn't work.

```
@image,name,where
\01\anton.jpg,Anton,NO
\01\gabriela.jpg,Gabriele,FI
\01\carla.jpg,Carla,SE
```

*Note: CSV actually stands for Comma-Separated Values, so i really don't see why Excel saves CSV with the `;` separator.*

Comment: It's a  windows language issue. For unknown reasons not English US versions of Windows (regional)  are set to use semi-colon instead of comma as a separator. And Excel is too much related to Win to be able to force use of comma in CSV.